# Stueckelberg mechanism in path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory

Suppose we have some gauge invariant Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_0$ depending on $A$ and some matter fields $\psi$, and we add a mass term for $A$.
$$\mathcal{L}[A,\psi]=\mathcal{L}_0[A,\psi]+m^2A^2$$ 
Now this Lagrangian is no longer gauge invariant.

Now let's look at the closely related related Lagrangian in terms of a Stueckelberg field $\phi$

$$\mathcal{L}_{St}[A,\psi,\phi]=\mathcal{L}_0[A,\psi]+m^2(A-\partial \phi)^2$$
This has gauge invariance, as long as we transform $\phi\rightarrow \phi+\theta$ when we transform $A\rightarrow A+\partial\theta$ (and the associated transformations on $\psi$).

We can choose a gauge in which $\phi$ vanishes everywhere, so it seems obvious enough at first glance that $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{St}$ lead to the same physics.

But here is what bothers me.

We can write $A$ as
$$A^{\mu}=A^{\mu}_{L}+\partial^{\mu}\xi$$
where $A_L$ is in the Lorentz gauge $\partial_\mu A_L^\mu=0$, and $\xi$ is some scalar function.

Then we can write the Lagrangian as
$$\mathcal{L}_{St}[A,\psi,\phi]=\mathcal{L}_0[A,\psi]+m^2A_L^2+m^2(\partial(\phi-\xi))^2$$
where the cross term vanished due to the Lorentz gauge condition on $A_L$.

Now if this is sitting in the path integral, we can redefine our field $\phi$ to absorb $\xi$, and integrate it out, and we get the new Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}'[A,\psi]=\mathcal{L}_0[A,\psi]+m^2A_L^2.$$

Any correlation functions of $\psi$ fields are the same calculated with either $\mathcal{L}_{St}$ and the integrated $\mathcal{L}'$. However it is not clear to me that they are the same as the original $\mathcal{L}$. In fact I think the correlation functions of $\psi$ might not be equivalent, because this $\mathcal{L}'$ is gauge invariant, since $\mathcal{L}_0$ and $A_L$ are. (On this last point, just to be clear, I'm calling $A_L$ gauge invariant because gauge transformations change $\xi$ but not $A_L$)

Do $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}'$ lead to the same physics? And if not where did I go wrong?

Comment: After thinking a bit more, I think the resolution is that $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}'$ are not equivalent in general, but are equivalent on gauge invariant correlation functions. This is important because it is perfectly reasonable to consider non-gauge invariant correlation functions in $\mathcal{L}$. I'm still interested in answers that might confirm or disagree with this resolution.